# Date based script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added a query in my site so that it will show div based on date. I have added 30 div in my site and added display none to them. Used the date based query to make one div active each day. Previously it is working when I have added that for 2 days. But when I am adding that for 30 day basis, it is not working for me. My url is [here](http://pmastropoint.com/).

You can check the code is executed [here](http://prntscr.com/ep4d8e).

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
  var current = new Date();
  var expiry  = new Date("March 26, 2017 12:00:00")
  var expiry2 = new Date("March 27, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry3 = new Date("March 28, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry4 = new Date("March 29, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry5 = new Date("March 30, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry6 = new Date("April 01, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry7 = new Date("April 02, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry8 = new Date("April 03, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry9 = new Date("April 04, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry10 = new Date("April 05, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry11 = new Date("April 06, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry12 = new Date("April 07, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry13 = new Date("April 08, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry14 = new Date("April 09, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry15 = new Date("April 10, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry16 = new Date("April 11, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry17 = new Date("April 12, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry18 = new Date("April 13, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry19 = new Date("April 14, 2017 12:00:00")
 var expiry20 = new Date("April 15, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry21 = new Date("April 16, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry22 = new Date("April 17, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry23 = new Date("April 18, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry24 = new Date("April 19, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry25 = new Date("April 20, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry26 = new Date("April 21, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry27 = new Date("April 22, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry28 = new Date("April 23, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry29 = new Date("April 24, 2017 12:00:00")
var expiry30 = new Date("April 25, 2017 12:00:00")
  if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
    $('.panchang_one').hide();
    $('.panchang_two').show();
  }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry2.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_two').hide();
       $('.panchang_three').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry3.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_three').hide();
       $('.panchang_four').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry4.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_four').hide();
       $('.panchang_five').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry5.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_five').hide();
       $('.panchang_six').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry6.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_six').hide();
       $('.panchang_seven').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry7.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_seven').hide();
       $('.panchang_eight').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry8.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_eight').hide();
       $('.panchang_nine').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry9.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_nine').hide();
       $('.panchang_ten').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry10.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_ten').hide();
       $('.panchang_eleven').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry11.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_eleven').hide();
       $('.panchang_twelve').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry12.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twelve').hide();
       $('.panchang_thirteen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry13.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_thirteen').hide();
       $('.panchang_fourteen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry14.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_fourteen).hide();
       $('.panchang_fifteen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry15.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_fifteen').hide();
       $('.panchang_sixteen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry16.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_sixteen').hide();
       $('.panchang_seventeen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry17.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_seventeen').hide();
       $('.panchang_eighteen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry18.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_eighteen').hide();
       $('.panchang_nineteen').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry19.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_nineteen').hide();
       $('.panchang_twenty').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry20.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twenty').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentyone').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry21.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentyone').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentytwo').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry22.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentytwo').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentythree').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry23.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentythree').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentyfour').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry24.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentyfour').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentyfive').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry25.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentyfive').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentysix').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry26.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentysix').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentyseven').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry27.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentyseven').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentyeight').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry28.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentyeight').hide();
       $('.panchang_twentynine').show();
   }
  else if(current.getTime()>expiry29.getTime()){
       $('.panchang_twentynine').hide();
       $('.panchang_thirty').show();
   }
}, 3000);
$('.panchang_one').show(); 
</script>
```

Can anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what does not work exactly? I have a feeling it is logic issue where the first case is always true when it should be applied to a case later down... AKA you need to check from the greatest number to the least number.

Comment: Yesterday the div for which the script is written is showing fine. But today it is not showing anything. My concern is to make one div display block per day. The first div was showing fine yesterday. Today the second div is meant to show, but not showing. Please check the place where the div content is meant to show in the above mentioned screenshot. When you inspect the element, you can get is better what I am referring.

Thank you for taking a look into it.

Comment: That is absolutely terrible code, so much repetition ... get used to working with loops and arrays. Plus, how long do you expect users to stay on your site? Running that check in an interval every 3 seconds seems over the top for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There's issue in your javascript logic. In your case, current date is always greater than the date in any of the expiry named variable, so always first **if statement** is executed, rest of the statement provided in **else if** block will never be executed. This is how the if  elseif statement work i.e., when condition in if block evaluates to true then do not execute elseif statement.
You will need to check current date with all expiry date variable i.e. with expiry , expiry2 , expiry3, expiry4 and so on.

Correction required:
Replace **else if** with **if**.

here's the correct logic:

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(function(){
      var current = new Date();
      var expiry  = new Date("March 26, 2017 12:00:00")
      var expiry2 = new Date("March 27, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry3 = new Date("March 28, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry4 = new Date("March 29, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry5 = new Date("March 30, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry6 = new Date("April 01, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry7 = new Date("April 02, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry8 = new Date("April 03, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry9 = new Date("April 04, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry10 = new Date("April 05, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry11 = new Date("April 06, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry12 = new Date("April 07, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry13 = new Date("April 08, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry14 = new Date("April 09, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry15 = new Date("April 10, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry16 = new Date("April 11, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry17 = new Date("April 12, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry18 = new Date("April 13, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry19 = new Date("April 14, 2017 12:00:00")
     var expiry20 = new Date("April 15, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry21 = new Date("April 16, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry22 = new Date("April 17, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry23 = new Date("April 18, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry24 = new Date("April 19, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry25 = new Date("April 20, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry26 = new Date("April 21, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry27 = new Date("April 22, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry28 = new Date("April 23, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry29 = new Date("April 24, 2017 12:00:00")
    var expiry30 = new Date("April 25, 2017 12:00:00")
      if(current.getTime()>expiry.getTime()){
        $('.panchang_one').hide();
        $('.panchang_two').show();
      }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry2.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_two').hide();
           $('.panchang_three').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry3.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_three').hide();
           $('.panchang_four').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry4.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_four').hide();
           $('.panchang_five').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry5.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_five').hide();
           $('.panchang_six').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry6.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_six').hide();
           $('.panchang_seven').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry7.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_seven').hide();
           $('.panchang_eight').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry8.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_eight').hide();
           $('.panchang_nine').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry9.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_nine').hide();
           $('.panchang_ten').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry10.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_ten').hide();
           $('.panchang_eleven').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry11.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_eleven').hide();
           $('.panchang_twelve').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry12.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twelve').hide();
           $('.panchang_thirteen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry13.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_thirteen').hide();
           $('.panchang_fourteen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry14.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_fourteen').hide();
           $('.panchang_fifteen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry15.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_fifteen').hide();
           $('.panchang_sixteen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry16.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_sixteen').hide();
           $('.panchang_seventeen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry17.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_seventeen').hide();
           $('.panchang_eighteen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry18.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_eighteen').hide();
           $('.panchang_nineteen').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry19.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_nineteen').hide();
           $('.panchang_twenty').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry20.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twenty').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentyone').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry21.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentyone').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentytwo').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry22.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentytwo').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentythree').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry23.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentythree').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentyfour').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry24.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentyfour').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentyfive').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry25.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentyfive').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentysix').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry26.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentysix').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentyseven').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry27.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentyseven').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentyeight').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry28.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentyeight').hide();
           $('.panchang_twentynine').show();
       }
       if(current.getTime()>expiry29.getTime()){
           $('.panchang_twentynine').hide();
           $('.panchang_thirty').show();
       }
    }, 3000);
    $('.panchang_one').show(); 
    </script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow its working. Some more adjustments required. I'll do that. But anyhow, the code is not working. Thanks again. :)

Comment: if my answer helped you to solve your question, then don't forget to approve/upvote my answer :)

Comment: Hello Reena, I do not have 15 reputation points. So I can not upvote your answer. But once I have 15 points, I surely comeback to this thread and upvote your answer.

Comment: @JitendraMishra You should still be able to accept the answer even if you don't upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

In your question I found it odd that you were hard coding all of the days. If you are planning to use `var current = new Date();` then this gets today's / current date, therefore you will literally have to update those hard coded values every single day for forever.

I took the liberty of converting your code into something more minimalistic. Clicking the `Click Me` button simulates the passing of days over the next 30 consecutive days relative to today's current date.

```js
// Create an ease of use function to add days to a given date
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
  var dat = new Date(this.valueOf());
  dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
  return dat;
}

// Start with all divs hidden
$('.panchang').hide();

// This will be called when our button is clicked
function start() {
  var today = new Date(); // get today's date
  var expiryDates = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; ++i) // store the dates of the next 30 days
    expiryDates.push(new Date().addDays(i));

  // Every 100 milli seconds, simulate the passing of 1 day
  var interval = setInterval(() => { 
    var keyDateIndex = null;
    // iterate expiry dates and see which dates we have surpassed
    for (let [index, value] of expiryDates.entries()) {
      if (today.getTime() > value.getTime()) 
        keyDateIndex = index;
      else
        break;

    }

    if (keyDateIndex == expiryDates.length - 1)
      clearInterval(interval);
    else
      today = today.addDays(1);

    // Show the correct divs
    $('.panchang').hide();
    $('.panchang:eq(' + keyDateIndex + ')').show();

  }, 100);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="start()">Click Me</button>
<div class="panchang">1</div>
<div class="panchang">2</div>
<div class="panchang">3</div>
<div class="panchang">4</div>
<div class="panchang">5</div>
<div class="panchang">6</div>
<div class="panchang">7</div>
<div class="panchang">8</div>
<div class="panchang">9</div>
<div class="panchang">10</div>
<div class="panchang">11</div>
<div class="panchang">12</div>
<div class="panchang">13</div>
<div class="panchang">14</div>
<div class="panchang">15</div>
<div class="panchang">16</div>
<div class="panchang">17</div>
<div class="panchang">18</div>
<div class="panchang">19</div>
<div class="panchang">20</div>
<div class="panchang">21</div>
<div class="panchang">22</div>
<div class="panchang">23</div>
<div class="panchang">24</div>
<div class="panchang">25</div>
<div class="panchang">26</div>
<div class="panchang">27</div>
<div class="panchang">28</div>
<div class="panchang">29</div>
<div class="panchang">30</div>
```